# What does 7 flashes- kernel image not found indicate

Tags: boot-issues, 64-bit, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, corrupt

I had a working 4B with 64 bit Bullseye running with ssh so I could work on it remotely.

It ran fine and was accessible for a week but I do suspect there was a power outage. It came back up but apparently has the 7 short flashes which indicates "kernel image not found"

I can't get to it directly for another week so hoping someone knows what that message means.

Is it corrupted from the power outage?

Or is it possible that the sd card has come partially dislodged?

The power cord is 3A pi plug but it does go thru a Genie remote power adapter. I don't think it should be a power issue based on message but thought I'd mention it.

Any ideas as to what it means. Is that standard (7 flashes) for a corrupt sd card?

Answer (score 3):

The "LED Warning Flash Codes" may be interpreted from [this table in the "Official Documentation"](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#led-warning-flash-codes). 7 flashes is said to indicate `Kernel image not found`. AFAIK, there is no diagnostic for a *"corrupt SD card"*, although my first guess would run in that direction.

Power outages can certainly cause corruption of any file system. The `ext4` file system was designed to alleviate the occurrence of that, but your kernel images are stored on the FAT32 `/boot` partition of the SD card, and so don't have the same resilience.

FWIW: I used to manage a remote RPi for a relative. The lass wasn't computer savvy, but she could replace an SD card  :)  So - I created a backup SD card for her to use in the case of failure.

Comment: I did find and mention the meaning of the 7 flashes, I was just hoping someone had seen that at the same time they had a boot screen to look at. I'll be going there shortly with my backup SD - and maybe invest in a small UPS too. Will report back

Comment: @dbmitch: Sorry the answer didn't help you.